# The min draw from F(x), where the max is an order statistic of the max draws from different, yet overlapping distributions?

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, extreme-value, order-statistics

Consider $m$ independent draws from each of $n$ distributions.   $X_{i,j}$ the $i_{th}$ draw from cdf $F_{j}(x)$. where $1 \leq  i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$.  Therefore we have $m\cdot n$ total draws from all distributions.  Also, assume the ranges of the distribution overlap.

Let us call $X_{\min,j}$ the minimum of all m draws for group $j$.  Similarly, $X_{\max,j}$ is the maximum of all $m$ draws for group $j$. Now,  $$\min_j{X_{\max,j}}$$ is the minimum of all the group maximums.  Let us label the group $j$ that contains this minimum as $y$.  How can I find the distribution of $X_{\min,y}$?  In other words, the distribution of the minimum value from the $F_{y}(x)$, when my only means of knowing which $F_{j}(x)$ is $F_{y}(x)$ is by the relative orderings of their maximum draws?

This is similar to – but more difficult than --  [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13259/what-is-the-distribution-of-maximum-of-a-pair-of-iid-draws-where-the-minimum-is/13286#13286) , which has been answered, and asks for a similar finding in the special case when all the distributions are the same:  $F_{1}(x) = F_{2}(x) =F_{n}(x)$.  I cannot figure out how to move from this answer to what I am looking for here.

Comment: it's inaccurate to say "when my only means of knowing which $F_{n}(x)$ is $F_{y}(x)$" They are not equal.

Comment: I think it's still ambiguous, since $F_j(x)$ is not $F_y(x)$. $F_y(x)$ comes only at the end of a long process, as you see in the answer. What you can say though it's "from which $X_j$ distribution comes $y$." But you don't need to edit the question again-just to let you know.

Comment: Thanks.  That's very helpful.  I'm entirely learning as I go along, so having examples of how to appropriately express ideas is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done along the lines of my previous answer with some changes.

1. In the first equation, I multiplied by $n$, which you cannot do here (because of lack of symmetry) so you have to calculate the probability for each $j$.  However, you can multiply by $m$ in the second equation(because there is symmetry within each group).
2. Hence you will not find one $Y$, but $n$ $Y_j$-s, which are maxima of $n-1$ minima of all groups except the $j$-th ones .
3. To find these, you would have to calculate the maximum of $n-1$ distributions, independent, but not identical. You can start with this problem(it is similar with when they are identical).

A CAS and a computer program would definitely help.

Comment: Thanks, Bogdan!$$ $$
Isn't the cdf of $Y_{j−s}$ equal to the product of all the other min cdfs? (And then I can just take the derivative to get the pdf)? So, if I understand correctly, I need to replace the "multiply by n" at the front of the other equation with "sum over all n" where, for each n, I substitute in the correct g(y)? But other than that, it stays the same? $$ $$
And to note, I am using Mathematica heavily :)

Comment: I think I got it.  Would the final equation (adjusted also for the change in looking now for the min of the group with smallest max) be:    
$$=\Sigma_{n=1}^{n}[ m\int_0^x f_{n}(w)[\int_0^w (F_{n}(y)-F_{n}(w))^{m-1}g_{n}(y)dy]dw]$$
Thanks so much, your answers have really helped.